# Nodejs error : libcouchbase.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: node.js, couchbase

I am working on a nodejs project. Its working in my laptop but when I tried to run it in my desktop it is throwing error :

libcouchbase.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Can anybody suggest me what could be the wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Install couchbase on your desktop machine.

Comment: Just forgot to mention, I am using ubuntu14.04LTS and couchbase is installed in it.

Comment: i bet that node or a library is trying to find that couchbase library and it's not in $PATH (or some other environment variable). another possibility is couchbase itself can't find the library?

Comment: Good to hear that. But can you be more specific what environment variable is missing??

Comment: Check your `/etc/ld.so.conf` (per [this](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ldconfig.8.html) man page), or add that path to your [LD_LIBRARY_PATH](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html).

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it could help somebody:
Looks like the shared library should be in [/usr/lib/libcouchbase.so.2](http://www.couchbase.com/autodocs/couchbase-c-client-2.1.1/libcouchbase.3lib.html) 
But the install script installed `libcouchbase.so.2` to /`usr/local/lib/libcouchbase.so.2.` So I just linked it to `/usr/lib/libcouchbase.so.2` and that works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the NODE_PATH environment variable to the path where the shared object resides. In my case

```
export NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib64
```

solved it.